# Algorithms for correlation of events/issues

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, devops

We are working on a system that aims to help development teams, SRE, DevOps team members by debugging many of the well known infrastructure issues (k8s to begin with) on their behalf and generate a detailed report which details report which details the specifics of the issue, possible root causes and clear next steps for the users facing the problem. In short, instead of you having to open up terminal, run several commands to arrive at an issue, a system does it for you and show it in a neat UI. We plan to leverage AI to provide better user experiences.

Questions:
1.There are several potential use case like predictive analytics, anomaly detection, forecasting, etc. We will not analysis application logs or metrics (may include metrics in future). Unlike application level logs, the platform logs are more unified. What is a good starting point for AI usage especially for platform based logs?

2.We plant to use AI to analysis issue correlations, we Apyori, FP Growth and got output. The output looks like below

```
| antecedent                 | consequent        | confidence | lift |
|----------------------------|-------------------| ---------- | ---- |
| [Failed, FailedScheduling] | [BackOff]         | 0.75       | 5.43 |
| [NotTriggerScaleUp]        | [FailedScheduling]| 0.64       | 7.29 |
| [Failed]                   | [BackOff]         | 0.52       | 3.82 |
| [FailedCreatePodSandBox]   | [FailedScheduling]| 0.51       | 5.88 |
```

FP Growth is data mining algorithm, from the output we can figure the pattern of events. There is one potential use case, save the previous output and compare it with latest output to detect abnormal pattern in the latest output. Can we use the output to inference issue correlations or any other scenario we can use the output?

3.Some logs seems irrelevant, but actually they have connections, like one host has issue, it will impact the applications running on it, the time span maybe long, how can we figure out this kind of relationships?
Any comments and suggestions will be greatly appreciated, thank you in advance.